# Is submodule of a finitely generated free $\mathbb{Z}G$-module free when $G$ is free?

Tags: group-theory, modules

We know that a submodule of a free $R$-module is not necessarily free. But if $R$ is a PID, then every submodule of a free $R$-module is free.

Now let $G$ be a free group of finite rank $r>1$ and $M$ be a finitely generated free $\mathbb{Z}G$-module. My question is that: Is every submodule  of $M$  free? What about a retract of $M$?

Recall that a module $N$ is called a retract of $M$ if there exist homomorphisms $f:N\to M$ and $g:M\to N$ such that $gf=id_{N}$.

What I've tried: If $N$ is a retract of $\mathbb{Z}G$-module of $M$, then $N$ is a direct summand of $M$. Since $M$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}G$-module, then $N$ is a projective $\mathbb{Z}G$-module. Now by a fact of H. Bass saying that finitely generated projective modules over free groups are free, we can conclude that $N$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}G$-module.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context . . . *again*. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Shaun I've edited my question and added what I've tried. Thanks a lot.

Comment: *Now by a fact of H. Bass saying that* huh... I'm interested in seeing that. Where can I find it?

Comment: @rschwieb Here you are: H‎. ‎Bass‎, ‎Projective modules over free groups are free‎, ‎notes‎, ‎Columbia University‎, ‎1964‎.

Comment: @rschwieb https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Projective-modules-over-free-groups-are-free-Bass/ebb682b9a480749c016d8e4364ace4d832aa4848

Comment: If $G$ is non-trivial, then $\mathbb{Z}G$ cannot be a PID, because the augmentation ideal is a non-zero non-maximal prime ideal. So, any principal ideal generated by a non-zero zero divisor and any non-principal ideal must be a non-free submodule.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang In a commutative ring you can't have free ideals of rank other than $1$, but it seems that since $G$ is a free group, it is not commutative. There are noncommutative rings with free ideals of rank other than 1.  It doesn't seem completely clear, then, that the last sentence of that comment follows

Comment: @M.Ramana When you say "free group" did you mean to include "abelian"?  that would simplify things considerably.

Comment: @rschwieb Of course not. I mean $G$ is just a free group of finite rank not necessarily rank 1.

Comment: @M.Ramana Just making sure. Some people mean that and don't think to say it because they have "commutative brain" or something.

Comment: @rschwieb You are right. Here I mean $G$ is a free group of finite rank $r>1$. I've edited my question. Thank you so much for your good point.

Comment: @M.Ramana i'd also like to note that most of the theorems in Bass' paper talk about *finitely generated* projective modules.  It seems like you are talking about all projective modules.  Please check to make sure you have said what you meant to say.

Comment: @M.Ramana One thing that makes me suspicious that it might not hold is that many of the sufficiency conditions for when the group ring is hereditary (which would be necessary in your situation) are often based on $G$ being finite.  Specifically, if $R$ is right hereditary and $G$ is a finite torsion-free group, $R[G]$ is right hereditary.  That doesn't disprove anything of course, but it's worth considering.

Comment: @rschwieb I'm so sorry. I forgot to write "finitely generated" in my question. I'll edit my question again.

Comment: @rschwieb You've got a point there. I'll consider it in my problem.